# How do I change the default start page for Google Apps when I have admin access?

Tags: google-workspace

This has been a pet peeve of mine lately. A few associates of mine set up a Google Apps account to help us manage some work. All was fine until I was granted admin access. Now, when I log in, it goes directly to the admin dashboard as opposed to the Gmail interface for my account.

There is often little reason for me to administrate anything, and I usually log in to check email or a doc. This extra step is annoying.

I tried searching the options everywhere I could think of. Is there a setting I have overlooked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this. However, if you follow their setup instructions, they will tell you to setup subdomains for specific services. So for example, mail.example.com will allow users at your domain to login directly to their mail. You do this by setting up a [CNAME record](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47283) which points to `ghs.google.com`. The complete instructions are available if you go to the administration page, then dashboard, then Email, then Change URL.

This simply makes it so when users type a domain such as `mail.example.com` it takes them to `http://mail.google.com/a/example.com`.

Comment: You nailed it! Setting up the CNAME works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the start page if you log in from http://www.google.com/a/example.com, but you can bookmark http://mail.google.com/a/example.com and log in there, and you'll be taken directly to your inbox after login.  From there, your different Google Apps are available in the upper-left.